# Como adicionar campos adicionais a um infotipo?

Tags: erp, infotype

Tenho a necessidade de efetuar uma customização em um infotipo (HR) adicionando dois novos campos para controle conforme representado, circulado de amarelo, na imagem abaixo:

[image: Infotipo HR - Garantia de Emprego]

Comment: Não percebo nada de SAP, mas eles tem um tutorial para o teu problema: [Enhancement of Standard Infotype](http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/HRABAP/Infotype/Enhancement.htm) (É Inglês, mas se precisares de ajuda, avisa!).

Comment: Isso envolve algo relacionado diretamente ao desenvolvimento de software? Usa ABAP ou alguma linguagem de programação ou é apenas uma configuração do SAP-HR?

Comment: @Zuul acho que você foi bem próximo, vou tentar seguir os passos

Comment: @bigown  acredito que seja uma melhoria no modulo imagino que não dê pra resolver via código, não tenho muita certeza, vou tentar decifrar o manual que o Zuul mandou

Comment: Parece que não é uma pergunta de desenvolvimento de software e está fora do nosso escopo por ser apenas do uso do software. Se isso estiver errado, podemos reabri-la depois, mas agora acho que ela deva ser fechada. Você pode continuar fazer outras perguntas de desenvolvimento de software. Sua outra pergunta, por exemplo, é muito boa. Veja a discussão sobre o que faz parte do tópico: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic

Comment: @bigown concordo e discordo, quando se diz respeito ao SAP sempre será 'uso de software' acredito que customização se enquadre por isso fiz a pergunta aqui, mas quando à codificação eu tenho que concordar. Obrigado pelos comentários

Comment: É bem polêmico. Se você for no link que eu passei, coloque lá uma resposta para estar no nosso foco perguntas desse tipo (Customização de ERP ou outros softwares que não envolvam código). Deixe o pessoal votar. Quem sabe o pessoal aceite. E aí ela seja válida. Até nos esforçamos para aceitar vários tipos de pergunta mas precisa ter um limite. Se o pessoal votar que quer isso, por mim, ok.

Comment: Farei isso, obrigado pelo apoio e desculpa qualquer coisa ;)

Comment: Na transação PM01, siga os passos [aqui](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/4f/d526cb575e11d189270000e8322f96/content.htm). Seu infotype parece ser o [0598](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/22/ff3039d803d94a83521f80002fe391/frameset.htm).

Comment: @Jordão Você acha que responde a pergunta? Coloque como resposta.

Comment: Você não conseguiu achar uma solução? Se achou posta aqui como resposta, pode ganhar reputação por isso.